# How to access controls from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have a user control test1.xaml and has a frame control name frame1. On my second user control, how do I reference the test1.xaml in my test2.xaml in order to manipulate the property of the control in test2.xaml.cs? Because I know that test1 test = new test1(); will not work because im not instantiating it and not referencing it. May I ask how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I will not write the code with DependencyProperties because It smells. I will write instead a simple code which does such stuff using MVVM. But I want to note that you must read an article "WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern" by Josh Smith.
Here is a simple code which contains one main window and two user controls Test1 and Test2. And only one ViewModel - GodViewModel, which is the viewModel for both Test1 and Test2. In fact, as a rule there are 1-1 mapping between ViewModel and View. I created only one ViewModel for the simplicity.

The window code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication99.MainWindow"
        x:Name="GodWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication99.View"
        Title="MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication99"
        DataContext="{Binding Vm, ElementName=GodWindow}">
    <StackPanel>
        <view:Test1 />
        <view:Test2 />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel.GodViewModel _vm = new ViewModel.GodViewModel();

    public ViewModel.GodViewModel Vm
    {
        get { return _vm; }
        set { _vm = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel code:

```
namespace WpfApplication99.ViewModel
{
    public class GodViewModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

test1 code (code behind is empty):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication99.View.Test1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="45" d:DesignWidth="167">

        <Button Content="{Binding Text}"
                Height="26" 
                Name="button1"
                Width="144" />
</UserControl>
```

test2 code (code behind is empty):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication99.View.Test2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Height="69" Width="232" />
</UserControl>
```

Using this code you can use the same property Text in both Test1 and Test2. In your question, you wrote that you had a property in test1 and want to use it in test2. So imagine that the solution provided just put the test1's one property Text into GodViewModel.
Perhaps, you want to use it in the code behind. In this case, you should create a separate ViewModel for test1 and test2 user controls. I'm not able to describe all details there. So, please read the article. I'm sure that MVVM pattern is a key thing in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

In the MVVM approach both views / user controls could use the same view model that they are data bound to. Now when the first control causes a value change in one of the properties exposed by that viewmodel this is automatically reflected in the second user control.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm already using MVVM but I already separated the files according to their folders. I'm trying to implement MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can add DependencyProperty of type YourViewModelBase to your test2. Than write some in the place you create an instance of your controls. Of course, if you use MVVM. However, as far as I understand, you should not do things like that according to MVVM.
if you don't have YourViewModelBase, you may create an abstract class for your test1 with necessary properties or just pass test1 as UserControl and then try to cast it to test1 in your test2 code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. could you provide a example code for how to implement that